# Difference between embedding ActiveX object with <object> tag or creating one with new ActiveXObject()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

I've noticed that there are 2 ways we can create ActiveX object in JavaScript, one is by embedding:

```
<object id="TestControl" classid="clsid:xxx-xx-xx-xx"></object>
```

and then later on obtain object using DOM:

```
var myControl = document.getElementById('TestControl');
```

Another way is to create instance of ActiveXObject:

```
var myControl2 = new ActiveXObject('Test.TestControl');
```

What exactly is different from ActiveX object perspective? Is one approach better then the other? Are there any differences in performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The two are pretty much equivalent.

The `<object>` notation is official HTML; `var myControl2 = new ActiveXObject('Test.TestControl');` can only be used in a scripting language like JScript or ASP; it isn't available for HTML directly.

Also: the "object" notation takes a class ID: all you need is the ActiveX object installed on your system (or installable over the Internet).  The Javascript example you gave has a PROGID ... which requires 1) the ActiveX object already be installed, and 2) the ActiveX object must have a PROGID (which is optional, not required, by ActiveX).

Comment: Hence `object` can be used in some degree even if user had turn JS off?